# Map image/texture to a predefined uneven surface (t-shirt with folds, mug, etc.)

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, 3d, textures

Basically I was trying to achieve this: impose an arbitrary image to a pre-defined uneven surface. (See examples below).

[image: Any image] --> [image]

I do not have a lot of experience with image processing or 3D algorithms, so here is the best method I can think of so far:

1. Predefine a set of coordinates (say if we have a 10x10 grid, we have 100 coordinates that starts with (0,0), (0,10), (0,20), ... etc. There will be 9x9 = 81 grids.
2. Record the transformations for each individual coordinate on the t-shirt image e.g. (0,0) becomes (51,31), (0, 10) becomes (51, 35), etc.
3. Triangulate the original image into 81x2=162 triangles (with 2 triangles for each grid). Transform each triangle of the image based on the coordinate transformations obtained in Step 2 and draw it on the t-shirt image.

Problems/questions I have:

1. I don't know how to smooth out each triangle so that the image on t-shirt does not look ragged.
2. Is there a better way to do it? I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheels here before I proceed with an implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: you could always increase the resolution and create tinier triangles :P I think you need a different algorithm instead of this triangulation. Something for shear and tear.

Comment: You could simply use a spline interpolation from "T-shirt coordinates" to texture coordinates. That way you get a smooth mapping from every pixel in the T-shirt image to the texture image and can simply look up the texture for each pixel. Won't work for creases or occlusions, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called *digital image warping*.  There was a [popular graphics text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0818689447) on it in the 1990s (probably from somebody's thesis).  You can also find an [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/an-algorithm-for-efficient-image-warping/184401431) on it from Dr. Dobb's Journal.

Your process is essentially correct.  If you work pixel by pixel, rather than trying to use triangles, you'll avoid some of the problems you're facing.  Scan across the pixels in target bitmap, and apply the local transformation based on the cell you're in to determine the coordinate of the corresponding pixel in the source bitmap.  Copy that pixel over.

For a smoother result, you do your coordinate transformations in floating point and interpolate the pixel values from the source image using something like [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a solution for the problem, it's just a workaround :

If you have the 3D model that represents the T-Shirt.
you can use directX\OpenGL and put your image as a texture of the t-shirt.
Then you can ask it to render the picture you want from any point of view.